# Image fetch or download from webservice

Tags: iphone, json, web-services, uiimageview

I stored images in server via php code. When i run the code in browser it displays only image name like string. Then im using `JSON` framework for fetching images from server. Is it possible to fetch image from server? Somebody told, it's not possible to fetch image from server. You need to use image URL otherwise it can't. What can i do?

Comment: Typically you would need the url of the server and path of the image on such server. And if your running the server locally, you would typically use localhost/(pathname)

Comment: Im using remote database not local server. I stored all the images in server url. But the url display one string. This is PHP file. I stored more than 20 images. Shall i write 20 url for 20 images?